# Doctrine Inheritance, Type of Child Entity

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine, mapping, entity

I'm using Doctrine in Symfony 2 Application.
I have abstract class Object which is parent Entity for all objects in my applications (tasks, deals etc.).

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="adm_object")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Repository\ObjectRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 */
abstract class Object extends BaseEntity
{
```

For example task entity declaration now:

```
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="crm_tasks")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Task extends Object
{
```

Now i want to make my own filter constraint in application using this function:

```
public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
```

The problem is that when i try to get type of entity by using $targetEntity->getName() it gives me 'Object', not 'Task'... Is there possible to find out which 'object' it is ? Because i have 10 objects in my applications so I need to know which object I have now in my SQL Query to write proper filter...

Below var_dump of $targetEntity variable:

```
object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)[1412]
  public 'name' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object' (length=29)
  public 'namespace' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity' (length=22)
  public 'rootEntityName' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object' (length=29)
  public 'customGeneratorDefinition' => null
  public 'customRepositoryClassName' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Repository\ObjectRepository' (length=50)
  public 'isMappedSuperclass' => boolean false
  public 'parentClasses' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'subClasses' => 
    array (size=12)
      0 => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Circle' (length=29)
      1 => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Address' (length=30)
      2 => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Note' (length=27)
      3 => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object1' (length=30)
      4 => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object2' (length=30)
      5 => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Tag' (length=26)
      6 => string 'Cloud\CalBundle\Entity\Event' (length=28)
      7 => string 'Cloud\CrmBundle\Entity\Contact' (length=30)
      8 => string 'Cloud\CrmBundle\Entity\Lead' (length=27)
      9 => string 'Cloud\CrmBundle\Entity\ContactInformation' (length=41)
      10 => string 'Cloud\CrmBundle\Entity\Deal' (length=27)
      11 => string 'Cloud\CrmBundle\Entity\Task' (length=27)
  public 'namedQueries' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'namedNativeQueries' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'sqlResultSetMappings' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'identifier' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'id' (length=2)
  public 'inheritanceType' => int 2
  public 'generatorType' => int 4
  public 'fieldMappings' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => 
        array (size=9)
          'fieldName' => string 'id' (length=2)
          'type' => string 'integer' (length=7)
          'scale' => int 0
          'length' => null
          'unique' => boolean false
          'nullable' => boolean false
          'precision' => int 0
          'columnName' => string 'id' (length=2)
          'id' => boolean true
      'add' => 
        array (size=9)
          'fieldName' => string 'add' (length=3)
          'type' => string 'datetime' (length=8)
          'scale' => int 0
          'length' => null
          'unique' => boolean false
          'nullable' => boolean true
          'precision' => int 0
          'columnName' => string 'add' (length=3)
          'quoted' => boolean true
      'mod' => 
        array (size=9)
          'fieldName' => string 'mod' (length=3)
          'type' => string 'datetime' (length=8)
          'scale' => int 0
          'length' => null
          'unique' => boolean false
          'nullable' => boolean true
          'precision' => int 0
          'columnName' => string 'mod' (length=3)
          'quoted' => boolean true
      'del' => 
        array (size=9)
          'fieldName' => string 'del' (length=3)
          'type' => string 'datetime' (length=8)
          'scale' => int 0
          'length' => null
          'unique' => boolean false
          'nullable' => boolean true
          'precision' => int 0
          'columnName' => string 'del' (length=3)
          'quoted' => boolean true
  public 'fieldNames' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string 'id' (length=2)
      'add' => string 'add' (length=3)
      'mod' => string 'mod' (length=3)
      'del' => string 'del' (length=3)
  public 'columnNames' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string 'id' (length=2)
      'add' => string 'add' (length=3)
      'mod' => string 'mod' (length=3)
      'del' => string 'del' (length=3)
  public 'discriminatorValue' => string 'object' (length=6)
  public 'discriminatorMap' => 
    array (size=13)
      'object' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object' (length=29)
      'circle' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Circle' (length=29)
      'address' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Address' (length=30)
      'note' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Note' (length=27)
      'object1' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object1' (length=30)
      'object2' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object2' (length=30)
      'tag' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Tag' (length=26)
      'event' => string 'Cloud\CalBundle\Entity\Event' (length=28)
      'contact' => string 'Cloud\CrmBundle\Entity\Contact' (length=30)
      'lead' => string 'Cloud\CrmBundle\Entity\Lead' (length=27)
      'contactinformation' => string 'Cloud\CrmBundle\Entity\ContactInformation' (length=41)
      'deal' => string 'Cloud\CrmBundle\Entity\Deal' (length=27)
      'task' => string 'Cloud\CrmBundle\Entity\Task' (length=27)
  public 'discriminatorColumn' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'type' (length=4)
      'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'length' => null
      'columnDefinition' => null
      'fieldName' => string 'type' (length=4)
  public 'table' => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'adm_object' (length=10)
      'options' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  public 'lifecycleCallbacks' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'entityListeners' => 
    array (size=1)
      'postPersist' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
  public 'associationMappings' => 
    array (size=4)
      'relation1' => 
        array (size=15)
          'fieldName' => string 'relation1' (length=9)
          'mappedBy' => string 'relation1' (length=9)
          'targetEntity' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\ObjectHasObject' (length=38)
          'cascade' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'orphanRemoval' => boolean false
          'fetch' => int 2
          'type' => int 4
          'inversedBy' => null
          'isOwningSide' => boolean false
          'sourceEntity' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object' (length=29)
          'isCascadeRemove' => boolean false
          'isCascadePersist' => boolean false
          'isCascadeRefresh' => boolean false
          'isCascadeMerge' => boolean false
          'isCascadeDetach' => boolean false
      'relation2' => 
        array (size=15)
          'fieldName' => string 'relation2' (length=9)
          'mappedBy' => string 'relation2' (length=9)
          'targetEntity' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\ObjectHasObject' (length=38)
          'cascade' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'orphanRemoval' => boolean false
          'fetch' => int 2
          'type' => int 4
          'inversedBy' => null
          'isOwningSide' => boolean false
          'sourceEntity' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object' (length=29)
          'isCascadeRemove' => boolean false
          'isCascadePersist' => boolean false
          'isCascadeRefresh' => boolean false
          'isCascadeMerge' => boolean false
          'isCascadeDetach' => boolean false
      'circle' => 
        array (size=19)
          'fieldName' => string 'circle' (length=6)
          'joinColumns' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'cascade' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'inversedBy' => null
          'targetEntity' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Circle' (length=29)
          'fetch' => int 2
          'type' => int 2
          'mappedBy' => null
          'isOwningSide' => boolean true
          'sourceEntity' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object' (length=29)
          'isCascadeRemove' => boolean false
          'isCascadePersist' => boolean false
          'isCascadeRefresh' => boolean false
          'isCascadeMerge' => boolean false
          'isCascadeDetach' => boolean false
          'sourceToTargetKeyColumns' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'joinColumnFieldNames' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'targetToSourceKeyColumns' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'orphanRemoval' => boolean false
      'user' => 
        array (size=19)
          'fieldName' => string 'user' (length=4)
          'joinColumns' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'cascade' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'inversedBy' => null
          'targetEntity' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\AdmUser' (length=30)
          'fetch' => int 2
          'type' => int 2
          'mappedBy' => null
          'isOwningSide' => boolean true
          'sourceEntity' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object' (length=29)
          'isCascadeRemove' => boolean false
          'isCascadePersist' => boolean false
          'isCascadeRefresh' => boolean false
          'isCascadeMerge' => boolean false
          'isCascadeDetach' => boolean false
          'sourceToTargetKeyColumns' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'joinColumnFieldNames' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'targetToSourceKeyColumns' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'orphanRemoval' => boolean false
  public 'isIdentifierComposite' => boolean false
  public 'containsForeignIdentifier' => boolean false
  public 'idGenerator' => 
    object(Doctrine\ORM\Id\IdentityGenerator)[1402]
      private 'sequenceName' => null
  public 'sequenceGeneratorDefinition' => null
  public 'tableGeneratorDefinition' => null
  public 'changeTrackingPolicy' => int 1
  public 'isVersioned' => null
  public 'versionField' => null
  public 'reflClass' => 
    object(ReflectionClass)[1390]
      public 'name' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object' (length=29)
  public 'isReadOnly' => boolean false
  protected 'namingStrategy' => 
    object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\DefaultNamingStrategy)[381]
  public 'reflFields' => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => 
        object(ReflectionProperty)[1401]
          public 'name' => string 'id' (length=2)
          public 'class' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object' (length=29)
      'add' => 
        object(ReflectionProperty)[1407]
          public 'name' => string 'add' (length=3)
          public 'class' => string 'Cloud\ApplicationBundle\Entity\BaseEntity' (length=41)
      'mod' => 
        object(ReflectionProperty)[1198]
          public 'name' => string 'mod' (length=3)
          public 'class' => string 'Cloud\ApplicationBundle\Entity\BaseEntity' (length=41)
      'del' => 
        object(ReflectionProperty)[1404]
          public 'name' => string 'del' (length=3)
          public 'class' => string 'Cloud\ApplicationBundle\Entity\BaseEntity' (length=41)
      'relation1' => 
        object(ReflectionProperty)[1408]
          public 'name' => string 'relation1' (length=9)
          public 'class' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object' (length=29)
      'relation2' => 
        object(ReflectionProperty)[1409]
          public 'name' => string 'relation2' (length=9)
          public 'class' => string 'Cloud\AdmBundle\Entity\Object' (length=29)
      'circle' => 
        object(ReflectionProperty)[1202]
          public 'name' => string 'circle' (length=6)
          public 'class' => string 'Cloud\ApplicationBundle\Entity\BaseEntity' (length=41)
      'user' => 
        object(ReflectionProperty)[1197]
          public 'name' => string 'user' (length=4)
          public 'class' => string 'Cloud\ApplicationBundle\Entity\BaseEntity' (length=41)
  private '_prototype' (Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo) => null
  public 'inheritanceMapping' => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => null
      'relation1' => null
      'relation2' => null
      'circle' => null
      'user' => null
      'add' => null
      'mod' => null
      'del' => null
```

Comment: do You need to use exactly this function? maybe try something else.

Comment: I have found in Doctrine/Orm/Filter only SQLFilter which my filter class extends. And in SQLFilter i can see only AddFilterConstraint with this 2 parameters so I think it's no other way to make global filter for all the queries in my application. The best solution would be something like DQLFilter because when I checked in DQLQuery there is correct entity - Task. But in SQLQuery there is automatically created join to Object entity and this is why in addFilterContstraint function parameter $targetEntity gives Object not Task entity name... I'm looking for a solution but I still not solved it.

Comment: can You please post var_dump($targetEntity) in Your question? There may be answer ;)

Comment: OK, one sec. But I was searching there and i didn't found anything.

Comment: It's now there for you mate ;-)

Comment: I found information that what i want to do is propably not possible ... According to this discussion -> http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2226                                 Any ideas for workaround ?